# Is it safe to use HMAC to create an API key?

Tags: authentication, hash, hmac, key

I am planning to create an API key using the user's password as message and a random number assigned to that user in my database as key (or vice-versa). I will then store the hash of that API key in my database.

This will make it possible to:

- Let users see their API keys whenever they want by typing their password
- Let users do this even though I never store the API key as plaintext in my database

Someone trying to get access to the API key would need to both know the plaintext password of the user and the random number assigned to that user in my database. Is this a secure way of creating api keys? Which hash algorithm should I be using if it is?

Comment: You would need to use a password hashing function as strong as the one you use to store passwords, otherwise leaking your database would make brute forcing the password easy. Ask yourself if being able to see the API key is useful. Also: what happens when a user changes their password, you've now lost that functionality unless they saved the old password (I don't). Instead, generate a long random key and show only the last few digits (and allow custom names for reference).

Comment: Okay it's a good point, it loses the functionality if the user changes their password. I often see APIs where I can see both my API key and my API secret at all times in the website. I wonder how they do it. Do they just store them as plaintext? In that case what's the point of having both a key and a secret? Even if it was just one key it wouldn't be a good idea to store it as plaintext right?

Comment: A lot of services store the API keys in plaintext. A DB compromise won't leak credentials used on other sites since they are randomly generated. I don't think it's a bad idea to do a simple hash (eg: sha256) of the key just to avoid accidental leaking through logs, but your solution seems overkill and prone to impacting the security of the password.